# Stay on the chosen navigation tab but also reaload it to see changed data after update

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have the edit form that I use to update data about practitioners, I want it to stay on the same tab called `#practitioner` (in which I have @include practitioner-display and @include practitioner-edit). To swap between those two includes I use `editPractitionerButton.js` (code below).

I have already made .js script that kind of does what I want, it stays on the #practitioner tab, but on the practitioner-edit, doesn't go to practitioner-display. Also, updated data isn't visible, it is only after manual website refresh.

my function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#practitioner_edit_form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : $(this).attr('action') || window.location.pathname,
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                //window.location = $('.nav-tabs a[href="#practitioner"]').tab('show');
                /*^reloads my page to http://rps.me/person/profile/49/[object%20Object] from http://rps.me/person/profile/49/Smith*/
                $('.nav-tabs a[href="#practitioner"]').tab('show');
                /*^stays in the form after submitting, changed data isn't visible, only after reload, but I want to reload to correct nav tab*/
                /*location.reload();*/
            },
            error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

controller function:

```php
public function updatePractitioner(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
                'effective_date' => 'required',
            ]
        );

        $fields = $request->all();
        $specialtyfields = (['effective_date'=>$request->get('effective_date_specialty'), 'expiry_date'=>$request->get('expiry_date_specialty')]);
        $primary_key = $this->PractitionerRepository->getIdName();
        $primary_key_specialty = $this->PractitionerSpecialtyRepository->getIdName();
        $practitioner_specialty_id = PractitionerSpecialty::where('practitioner_id', $id)->value('practitioner_specialty_id');
        $fields[$primary_key] = $id;
        $this->PractitionerRepository->update($fields);
        $specialtyfields[$primary_key_specialty] = $practitioner_specialty_id;
        $this->PractitionerSpecialtyRepository->update($specialtyfields);
        return back()->with('successUpdate', 'Practitioner has been updated!');
    }
```

form file (only buttons):

```php
<form> [...]

            <button type="submit"
                    class="btn btn-editpanel btn-success btn-round">Save changes
            </button>
            <!-- end /.footer -->
            <button id="update-cancel-button-practitioner" href="javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href" type="button"
                    class="btn btn-editpanel btn-danger btn-round">Cancel
            </button>
</form>
```

editPractitionerButton.js

```
function editPractitionerButton() {
    var editInfoSelector = $('.edit-practitioner');
    var viewInfoSelector = $('.view-practitioner');
    var editBtnSelector =  $('#edit-practitioner-btn');

    editInfoSelector.css('display', 'none');
    editBtnSelector.click(function(){
        if (viewInfoSelector.is(':visible')) {
            viewInfoSelector.css('display', 'none');
            editInfoSelector.css('display', '');
        } else {
            viewInfoSelector.css('display', '');
            editInfoSelector.css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
}
```

So I want it to refresh the page and then go to #practitioner tab. Maybe instead of js file, I can make a specific return in controller function?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the laravel, instead of javascript, you can follow this,

From the tab, you can pass a hidden value of tab name, and in the controller, you can session flush it,

`session()->flash('active', 'tab-name');`

and in the view, you can check the value and make it active.

```
@if(session()->get('active') == 'tab-name') 'active' @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the `#practitioner` content showed after a page reload, you could use a local storage using the following steps.

1. Attach a `name` attribute on the `<a>` tab link
2. Get the selected tab name and save it into a local storage
3. reload the page, and trigger the selected tab based from the previously stored tab name

For example you have elements like this :

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#practitioner" name="practitioner">Practitioner</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs2" name="tabs2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs3" name="tabs3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>

<div id="practitioner">
    <p>practitioner content</p>
</div>

<div id="tabs2">
    <p>tabs2 content</p>
</div>

<div id="tabs3">
    <p>tabs3 content</p>
</div>
```

Add this code at the end of the javascript block :

```
var currTab = localStorage.getItem("tab");
if (currTab) {
    $('a[name="' + currTab + '"]').trigger("click");
}
```

And add this code into the ajax success response to set the local storage and trigger the reload page :

```
var tab = $("#tabs li a.active").attr("name");
localStorage.setItem("tab", tab);
location.reload();
```

So the javascript code will be like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#practitioner_edit_form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : $(this).attr('action') || window.location.pathname,
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                //window.location = $('.nav-tabs a[href="#practitioner"]').tab('show');
                /*^reloads my page to http://rps.me/person/profile/49/[object%20Object] from http://rps.me/person/profile/49/Smith*/
                // $('.nav-tabs a[href="#practitioner"]').tab('show');
                /*^stays in the form after submitting, changed data isn't visible, only after reload, but I want to reload to correct nav tab*/
                /*location.reload();*/
                var tab = $("#tabs li a.active").attr("name");
                localStorage.setItem("tab", tab);
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
    var currTab = localStorage.getItem("tab");
    if (currTab) {
        $('a[name="' + currTab + '"]').trigger("click");
    }
});
```